# Add string to 1-D cell array without determing its length in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have some strings in `file.txt` and I want to add all of it to a cell array.

But the problem is a number of strings in file are unknown and I don't want to count. I want each time I read 1 string in file (from top to bottom), I'll add it to cell array.

Example:

```
**file.txt**

ABC
DEFG
HI
JKLMNO

--> cellarray(1) = 'ABC', cellarray(2) = 'DEFG', cellarray(3) = 'HI', cellarray(4) = 'JKLMNO'
```

I'm using MATLAB **R2014b**. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this in a lot of ways. You can read one line at the time and and the strings one by one. You can also use built in functions, which do this for you. Depending on what you have in the file, there are different options. You should begin by reading the documentation in [textscan](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

Comment: @patrik I use textscan but each time they read new string, they delete last cell string. So the result is I have a cell size 1 x 1, which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to load your entire file into a cell array of strings. The result is going to be a `1 x 1` cell array because you only have one format specifier (`%s`) but that cell array will contain *another* cell array of all of the lines in the file.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'rt');
data = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\r\n');

C = data{1};

%// 'ABC'
%// 'DEFG'
%// 'HI'
%// 'JKLMNO'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a line from text file using the `fgets` function in MATLAB  ([Documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com))

Comment: A small demo or more explanation of that MATLAB function would improve your answer.